# What is another word or way to say "can't be helped"

Tags: single-word-requests

An example scentence:
It can’t be helped that some dog breeds have more potential to cause serious harm to a person, if the dog were to decide to attack.

Answer (score 1):

> **Certainly** some dog breeds have more potential...

Alternatively, you could use "inevitable" if you change to future tense.

> It is **inevitable** that some dog breeds will have more potential...

Comment: Thank you... I was thinking "inevitable" Just wanted another opinion. I'll take it! ☺